# Incoming call notifications not working - Phone state

Tags: notifications, calls, call-history, call-screening, telephony

In my Android phone, Incoming calls notification is not working.Out going is working fine.

Actually Whenever I am calling my mobile from my friend's mobile, Its saying "line is busy".
If I visit call logs in my mobile, I can see My friend's number in the log. 
I was having this issue for past 4 days.

Thankfully, I checked the logfile(log.txt which resides in phone memory somewhere. I guess its the log of the whole phone) of my phone. In that file I can see the following log message 5 times like below.

```
Phonestate: Incoming call notify is disabled
Phonestate: Incoming call notify is disabled
Phonestate: Incoming call notify is disabled
Phonestate: Incoming call notify is disabled
Phonestate: Incoming call notify is disabled
```

I guess,  I have to change this phone state, I dont know how to change that. Can u help me out?

Comment: Could you mention your device model and Android version? Also, did this occur recently, or from the first time since you bought it?

Comment: Also, did you by any chance set "call forwarding", "call divert", or similar feature? In case it is, could you try replacing the SIM card with others to test?

Comment: Yea. I ve replaced the sim nd tested. In all the sims, the pbm persists. Call forwarding is not enabled. FYI. 
I am using Redmi 2S MIUI

Answer (score 0):

I just changed my whole software in REDMI Authorised service center. 
I guess the update corrupted my Operating system.